# Agrupar personas unicamente cuando los resultados sean diferentes de NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Necesito agrupar los nombres de las personas cuando ninguno de sus resultados sean nulos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo agrupar a pedro, ana y enrrique porque ninguno de  sus resultados fueron nulos, los demas ignorar.

La sentencia actual que estoy usando es:

```
SELECT a.`Nombre`,
      a.`Apellido`,
      IF(`Calificacion`>=8, "YES", NULL) AS resultado 
FROM `calificacion` AS c 
INNER JOIN alumno AS a ON a.`Matricula`=c.`idAlumno`
```

Comment: Nos muestras lo que llevas al momento por favor?

Comment: Si gracias acabo de editar la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agrupar los que no sean `NuLL` aplicando el filtro

```
WHERE resultado IS NOT NULL
```

Pero si lo que quieres es que no tengan ningún `NULL` deberías hacer una subconsulta

```
SELECT a.`Nombre`,
      a.`Apellido`,
      IF(`Calificacion`>=8, "YES", NULL) AS resultado 
FROM `calificacion` AS c 
INNER JOIN alumno AS a ON a.`Matricula`=c.`idAlumno`
WHERE b.idAlumno not in (
    select idAlumno from calificacion where Calificacion is not null
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes tratar colocando un `WHERE` para primero filtrar aquellos valores que no son nulos

```
WHERE resultado IS NOT NULL
```

> Dentro del filtro que proporciona la condición del WHERE usamos el alias que le diste a la columna generada por el condicional

Posterior agrupas por las columnas por tus tres columnas así

```
GROUP BY a.nombre, a.apellido, resultado
```